# WordPress 投稿の1つめのimgタグをdivで囲いたい

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

WordPressを使っています。投稿（記事ページなど）内にある1つめのimgタグをdivで囲いたいので以下のようなコードを書いてみましたがどうにこもうにも動きません。どのようにすればいいでしょうか。

```
function firstimg_add_divtag($content){
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];

  $content = preg_replace($first_img , '<div><img alt=""${1}></div>', $content);
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'firstimg_add_divtag');
```

お手数ですがご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

*参考リンク*
http://kotori-blog.com/wordpress/entry_first_img/
http://nelog.jp/no-alt-fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

単純に置換するだけなので

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace( '/<img[^>]*>/iu', '<div>$0</div>', $content, 1 );

    return $content;
}, 20 );
```

でいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: とても参考になりました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

おそらくこちらの関数はimgのsrc部分だけを抽出するものだとおもいます。
ですので$first_imgには画像のパスが入っていると思います。

テーマファイルで関数を呼び出す際にdivを付けてしまったほうが
てっとり早い気もします。

呼び出す側のテーマファイルに↓

```
<div><img src="<?php echo firstimg_add_divtag(); ?>" /></div>
```

もし頑張って正規表現をやってみるなら
正規表現の部分を変えればいけると思います。